# Unbalanced Dataset: Oversampling vs Repeat

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, resampling

I am facing a **Machine Learning** Task on a highly **unbalanced dataset**.

Since the smallest class has a tiny number of examples (something like 2 hundreds w.r.t to the biggest that is 200 thousand). I need to perform **oversampling** (to be more precise I would oversample the smaller classes, and undersample the bigger ones to an intermediate value of examples, but this is out of the scope of this question).

Now, I have two options to do that:

1) **Random sample** (of course with replacement) examples from the smallest class

2) **Repeat n times** the examples from the smallest class

Any advice on which is the best way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's probably different for different applications.  Can you run tests on like 10% (1%?) of your total data?  Just pull that randomly, and play around with over/under/random/repeat sampling, and see what kind of score/MSE/loss you can get

Answer (score 0):

As Mohammed Athar mentioned you can just try which of your menioned approaches works better.

Additionally you could try to split your "large" class into (large_class/small_class) splits randomly! 
Then you train a classifier (where you have all data from the small class and only a part of the large class) for every split you have.

At the end you can combine all your classifiers with bagging/boosting/neural_network/other_model.